# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1]

Tags: java, json, parsing, opensearch

I have the following code in Java. I'm trying to query Opensearch and parse the response.

```
Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

The final line throws the following exception

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1]
```

Here is the output of the println:

```
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

This looks like a valid JSON to me. Why is it throwing an error? I also tried to trim the string, still the same error. What am I missing?

Edit: Alright, I was able to solve it by doing the following:

```
Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(responseString);
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString));
```

I'm not sure why this fixed it. I wonder someone can give an idea.

Comment: What happens if you execute ```System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));``` twice? Is it possible that the ```getEntity()``` method consumes the underlying data and it is empty on the second run?

Comment: yes, the entity is consumed by the first `EntityUtils.toString()` call and therefore the parse fails.  by saving the response string to a local variable, you can safely reprocess the results multiple times.